# Encountering probles install cocoapods (Xcode)

Tags: ruby, xcode, cocoapods

I'm having issues installing cocoa pods to my college's computer. I talked to the technical director for the CS department, who used admin privileges to SSH into my computer and install cocoa pods. However, when I try to call pod install onto the directory where the Xcode project lies, I get the following error.

`Preparing`


`Analyzing dependencies`


`Updating spec repositories
Updating spec repo master
  $ /usr/bin/git pull --ff-only
  Already up-to-date.`


`` Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using ARCHS setting to build architectures of target Pods: ()
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Edify Testing`: () ``


`Finding Podfile changes
  - OBShapedButton
  - ObjectAL-for-iPhone
  - UIMenuItem-CXAImageSupport
  - UIView-Autolayout`


`Resolving dependencies of Podfile
Finished resolution (0 steps) (Took 0.764299 seconds) (2015-05-28 17:33:19 -0500)
[!] Unable to find a specification for ObjectAL-for-iPhone (~> 2.5)`


`` /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:395:in handle_resolver_error'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:64:inrescue in resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:55:in resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:440:inblock in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:59:in section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:438:inresolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:63:in analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:196:inanalyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:114:in block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:59:insection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:113:in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:93:ininstall!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:71:in run_install_with_update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:101:inrun'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:312:in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:46:inrun'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/bin/pod:44:in <top (required)>'
/usr/bin/pod:23:inload'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `' ``

I have tried replacing the single quotes in the the Podfile, which did not work. I get the following error instead:

`Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for OBShapedButton`

Comment: Did you updated to the latest version of cocoa pods ?

Comment: @Antzi probably yes, as in his logs is `cocoapods-0.37.2`